# what is the most aggresive FLUSH / RESET mysql command to clear query cache (and anything else...)

Tags: mysql, caching, reset, flush

i am reading here on mysql.com, there are multiple variants of this FLUSH / RESET command.

what is the most aggressive method of flushing EVERYTHING POSSIBLE (caches, buffers, EVERYTHING) from mysqld?

we want to get as close to 'just started' as possible, without shutting down the daemon.

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess these should do:

```
RESET QUERY CACHE;
FLUSH STATUS, TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
```

Please read the appropriate manual sections and make sure you know what you are doing ;)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reset.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/flush.html